# Lodash - cannot read 'has' of undefined

Tags: webpack, lodash, undefined

Using Node 14.0, bundling with webpack, wherever I import lodash I get the error `cannot read 'has' of undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the root directory of the project contains brackets (`project-[1.2]`). Remove the brackets form the project folder and the issue disappears.